# Java: pass a non void method with parameter as a parameter of another method

Tags: java, function

I'm struggling with a little java trick which is: how to pass a non void method with one parameter as a parameter (or two) of another method ?
I guess this will involve Function or Biconsumer, and I've been trying with it. But I didn't manage to make it work...
The exact context is quiet simple: I'm working on Fix messages with Quickfixj librairy and I need to call in the class Message:

- getInt(int tagValue) returning an int,
- getString(int tagValue) returning a String,
- getChar(int tagValue) returning a char.

I've been trying this:

```java
public static < T > void setFieldsMap(int fieldTag,
                                          Function< Integer, T > messageGetter,
                                          String fieldKey ) throws FieldNotFound {
            this.fieldsMap.put( fieldKey, String.valueOf( messageGetter.apply( fieldTag ) ) );
}
```

Which I wanted to call like that:

```java
setFieldsMap( myTag, message::getString, "MY_KEY" );
```

But this doesn't compile. **I'm getting the following error: "int is not a functional interface".**

Of course I already checked Google but it didn't give me a fitting solution. I only found solution to call a method without parameter.

I've been using Function to call a getter without parameter, or Biconsumer to call a setter with a parameter. But it seems that calling a non void method with one parameter isn't that easy...

**Does anyone has a clue to make this work? Thanks a lot for your time and your help guys!**  :)

Comment: What's `fieldsMap` and why would it accept a random `T` as a value?

Comment: The first test to expose a misuse of a method reference is to try to create a variable in an assignment context: `Function<Integer, T> messageGetter = message::getString;` (substituting the concrete type for whatever `T` is). This moves it out of potentially tricky contexts and tells you where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the current form the code won't compile because you can't really access `this.` from the static method.

Other than that you can start off with the following (I've removed the irrelevant parts):

```
class Sample {
    public static < T > void setFieldsMap(int fieldTag,
                                         Function< Integer, T > messageGetter,
                                         String fieldKey )  {
         messageGetter.apply(fieldTag);

    }

}
public class SampleTest {

    private static String toString(Integer  val) { // an example of method
        System.out.println("Converting " + val);
        return val.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample.setFieldsMap(123, SampleTest::toString, "someKey");
    }
}
```

Another point to consider is that `T` is not really used, so it can be substituted with `?`

```
class Sample {

    public static void setFieldsMap(int fieldTag,
                                    Function< Integer, ? > messageGetter,
                                    String fieldKey )  {
         messageGetter.apply(fieldTag);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to be working! Unfortunately I still have a pb with the handling of an exception that my method is supposed to throw. But it seems I'm obliged to surround each invocation of this method with a try/catch. Otherwise it doesn't compile..

Answer (score 2):

You method input argument `Function< Integer, T > messageGetter` means that you have to supply a function or method reference that takes an `Integer` as input and returns `T` as output.

The method reference `message::getString` is not a valid input argument, because `getString(String s)` takes a `String` as input, not an `Integer`.

Just imagine if you could supply that argument, then the method's implementation `messageGetter.apply(fieldTag)` would essentially read as `message.getString(fieldTag)`, which would not work, because `fieldTag` is an `int`.

Comment: actually, `getString()` takes a int as parameter. It is named as `getString` because it returns a String.
https://www.quickfixj.org/javadoc/1.6.3/quickfix/FieldMap.html#getString(int)

Comment: Well, then your remark _"getString(String s) returning a String"_ in the original question is misleading...